# In Chrome, is there a way to search only within my bookmarked sites?

Tags: google-chrome, search

I'm not trying to search for a bookmark - I'm trying to search for a term that may appear on one of my bookmarked sites.

For instance, if I wanted to search on the term "Obama" and restrict my query to the New York Times web site, I know I could type this into the main URL/Search bar in Chrome:

obama site:nytimes.com

I'm wondering if there's a way to change that so that it's effectively:

obama site:*any one of the sites in my Chrome bookmark folder*

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a good idea for an extension.

Comment: Truly! I've never written a Google extension but this might push me over the edge. Unfortunately right now I'm slammed with client work (which is why I was looking for this time-saver in the first place, ha!).

Comment: Not specifically what you want, but opera can search cached pages for content through the history tool. If you've visited the page recently, you should be able to search it.

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous: are you saying that you want to search all pages that are on a host that appears in your bookmarks list?

Comment: Not an answer, but Firefox's add-on "Bookmark Tools" does what you want.

Comment: @intuited: Yes, the OP wants to search through the content of bookmarked pages.

Comment: @musicfreak: Hmmrmm.. that's not what I supposed, though: searching the content of bookmarked *pages*, e.g. http://www.nytimes.com/2010/12/14/health/policy/14health.html?_r=1&hp , is not the same as searching bookmarked *sites*; e.g. the presence of a bookmark to that particular article would engender, in this latter case, a search over the entire nytimes.com website, searching all articles currently published by the journal.  In the former case, it would just add that specific article to the list of resources to be searched.  My take on the question is that the OP wants to generalize thusly.

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108034/adding-favorite-websites-to-google-search

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just released a Google Chrome extension called [SearchMark](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cidphbjheamggcklpgfibhdhkkgpnbkm?hl=en) that will do exactly what you want. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Hooray!!! A free solution. I've installed and tried it out, and it works okay. I'd really like if it performed searches more traditionally, though. For instance if I search on the quoted words "control panel" it brings back results for "control" and "panel" - not the two together. BUT, hey, at least it's free and doens't require me signing up for another service. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I am working on this. The next version should have that feature.

Comment: It crashes in Chromium 11.0.696.65 (84435) Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: I have been searching for such a tool for YEARS!

Comment: Erm, it kind of uninstalled itself in the latest chrome update, probably because of change of rules... i know shouldn't be whining, I'm going to spend some time to fix it myself... but it would be more efficient if the owner knows what should be done

Comment: The tool was abandoed in 2011 and does not work in modern chrome due to inline js code security restrictions. I made [a fork with the fixes](https://github.com/klesun/SearchMark), you are welcome.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the browser-based [Historio.us](http://historio.us/).

This is what makeuseof.com says in [Historious Takes Bookmarks To The Next Level](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/historious-takes-bookmarking-level/):

> The idea behind Historious is simple.
>   Instead of storing bookmarks in
>   folders, they’re all individually
>   indexed; just like Google does with
>   the whole of the internet, to create
>   your personalized search world. This
>   search engine, which can be used in
>   every browser, across computers,
>   allows you to **search both by title and content of the indexed pages**.
>
> Historious works across browsers by
>   bookmarklet. A bookmarklet is a
>   (regular) bookmark that executes a bit
>   of Javascript code. You’ll be able to
>   add it to your bookmarks bar after
>   you’ve completed (free) registration.
>   Alternatively, there’s also a Google
>   Chrome extension. This works exactly
>   the same as the bookmarklet, and
>   nothing keeps you from using the
>   extension on one computer and the
>   bookmarklet on another.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems Google has a custom search you can point to your bookmarks file.  From their doc, "Here's a quick and easy way to create a search engine from the links on your web page":
  http://www.google.com/cse/tools/create_onthefly

The way I use it, I have to export my bookmarks from xbel to an .html file, but that's a useful thing to have anyway.  (Especially since I haven't found a Chrome equivalent to Galeon's "My Portal").

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+Shift+O opens the Bookmark Manager page
There's a Search bar/box in the top left corner that allows your to search through your bookmarks

Comment: I'd like to search through the sites that are bookmarked, not just the bookmarks themselves which is what that search does. thanks tho!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find/write a Chrome extension to do this, you could

#### A) get a list of your bookmark URLs

I initially thought that the `Bookmarks` file in the chrome profile directory was an sqlite3 DB like some of the other files in there.  This is incorrect.  It looks like a JSON file, so what you'll probably want to do is to import it into some scripting language that has JSON facilities (pretty much anything beginning with 'p' is a safe bet, or even JS if you want to use rhino/spidermonkey/etc) and then extract certain elements.

At first glance, it looks like you'll want the `url` property of each object that has a 'type' property equal to `"url"`.  There are some complications though: for example, this will also include bookmarklets and other things that don't have [relevant] sites, so you'll probably want to run a filter on the results to restrict them to actual web URLs.  Whatever you use in **B** to get the sites might test for this first anyway and return an error on invalid URLs.

#### B) reduce the list of bookmark URLs (**A**) to the list of hosts they use

I *think* this is what you want?  Or maybe domains?  Except if it's like *.co.uk or similar?  This is probably most sensibly done in the same script that you use in **A**.  Another option is to pipe it through a `sed | sort | uniq` filter, though with that option you don't end up actually parsing the URL, and you have to bust out some ghetto regex for it.  `php` is really good at this sort of thing.  Well, compared to its appropriateness for most tasks.

#### C) build a google query URL

...by prefixing each item from **B** with `site:`, joining them with the string `+OR+`, and then url-encoding and appending (after a `+`) the specific text you want to do a search on.  You stick the result on the end of a string like `http://www.google.com/search?q=`.

This should give you a URL like http://www.google.com/search?q=site:superuser.com+OR+site:stackoverflow.com+chrome

Then you should be able to just pass that URL as the first argument to a command-line invocation of `google-chrome` to get it to open a new tab containing the search results.  Note that, least under `bash`, you'll need to wrap the URL in quotes so that it doesn't get shell expansion applied to it.

So if you want to, you can roll this into a command line utility, and then just run it by passing your search terms to it.  If Chrome is running, you should probably make a copy of the `Bookmarks` file before reading it in, and then delete the temp file afterwards.

If you already know JS, and especially if you don't know command-line-friendly scripting languages, it might be easier to learn how how to write a Chrome extension than to rig this up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is to use the bookmark manager. You could make your own search engine just searching your bookmarked sites, but that's a little far fetched I guess. I guess the best way is to use the book manager by pressing shift+ctrl+b.

Comment: Ctrl-shift-b only allows me to search for bookmarks, not for a term on the bookmarked sites. I'm playing around with creating a Google custom search engine (google.com/cse) but it's more manual than I'd hoped; I still need a way to get sites I bookmark over into CSE.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you CAN search for them but you have to use the dedicated searchbox for bookmarks in the manager http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95714

Comment: No, this only searches the actual bookmarks, not the pages the bookmarks are pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be actually a straight forward solution, but then you can use [Historio.us](http://historio.us). It's a social bookmarking tool that lets you search your bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and search your history, and that might yield [some results](http://chrome://history/#q=obama&p=0).

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating a bunch of `site:` parameters (e.g., `site:superuser.com OR site:stackoverflow.com+chrome ...`) will run into Google's limit of 32 words per query. Minus the query term, that means you would only be able to search through 31 different domains that you've bookmarked.